# IdentityServer 4- ASP.net webapi (non core) - Missing ApiResource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, identityserver3

**Given**

I've a identityserver v4 running.
A Javascript client creates a token and accesses a asp.core api with the generated accesstoken.

In Asp Core Api I have this code which works

```
             services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = authority;
                options.ApiName = "myApi";
            });
```

In IdentityServer I defined "**myApi**" as a **ApiResource**.

**Problem**

Now I wanted to include another api which is older webapi and written with .net4.6.1 . But all calls to this api end in a **401**

Using same request to the core api with same token works.

The code to for the looks like this:

```
      JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
      var options = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = identServer,
            RequiredScopes = new List<string>
            {
                "myApi"
            }
        };

        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(options);
```

But the tokens that are working the core project doen't work there.
One thing i can see is that i can't set a api name in the IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions .

Currently i'm using the IdentityServer**3**.AccessTokenValidation Nuget package. Maybe thats related to the problem ?

I can't use IdentityServer**4**.AccessTokenValidation due to some dependency issues there.
For example there are only AddOptions for the netcore authentication builders

[image]

With jwt.io i also cheked the token and can see t hat myApi is part in `aud` and in `scope`

I also tried to set no required scopes still i got 401

Some time ago i tested this with the identity server v3 there it worked.

Also i don't see any Validation errors in the logs. What am I missing to get the errors of the api token validation logged?

What am I missing?

**Update**
When setting the validationmode to the endpoint  i got a exception in the identityserver.

> fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ApiSecretValidator[0]
>         No API resource with that name found. aborting fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.IntrospectionEndpoint[0]
>         API unauthorized to call introspection endpoint. aborting.

Unfortuenatly it doesn't tell me what the api is he is expected ....
As mentioned before "myApi" is defined as ApiResource but how to set the api name in the non core environment ?

Comment: "But the tokens that are working the core project doen't work there." So what do you get?

Comment: sorry forgot to write. i get a 401

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to use `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` when authenticating against IDS4, don't worry about that.

Try this:

In the `Startup.cs` of your **.net4.6.1** app, in your `IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions` there is a property `ValidationMode`. Set it to `ValidationMode.Both` and try again.

Comment: chekced it same result, ends in 401

Comment: Do you have logging enabled on the identity server? If yes check what does the log say. If not - enable it and try again, to see what will the log say.

Comment: Yes. see my update from right now pls. after setting validation to the endpoint i got a error. it seems like it expects a api ressource but i cant see which one he is expection

Comment: 2 things come to my mind now. First check your `.well-known/openid-configuration`, and make sure that the scope that you are requesting is in the `scopes_supported` part. Then - make sure that you are adding this scope to your client's allowed scopes, when configuring IdentityServer (both steps on IdentityServer side). I'm not sure that this is an issue, but - why don't you try with 2 different scopes for the 2 api's just to make it work, and then you can try again with one and the same. I have the exact same configuration, but with 2 scopes and it works (not guaranteed that it is a problem).

Comment: this wasnt the case. finally if ound it out ill post it here as an answer maybe it will save someone elses time

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that when i authenticate with an non core api, the api ressource needs to have an secret, then the api resource name and secret has to be set in the api.

Here:

In IdentityServer

```
new ApiResource("myApi", "My Test API")
{   
  ApiSecrets = new List<Secret>()
  {
    new Secret("435tgsdgfdg".Sha256()) // This wasnt required when attaching a .net core api
  }
}
```

and the configuration in the netfx webapi is then:

```
var options = new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
  {
    ClientId = "myApi",
    ClientSecret = "435tgsdgfdg",
    RequiredScopes = new List<string> { "myApi"},            
    Authority = identtityServerUri,
    DelayLoadMetadata = true
  };
```

For asp core webapi's there was no need neither for me to set the secret in identityserver nor set clientid and client secret in the client.